# People who do not drink tea

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a specific term that can be used for the people who do not drink *tea* or *coffee* like there is *vegetarian* in case of meat?

Comment: Mormons? I think you need to be more specific.... **Why** don't they drink these beverages?

Comment: Typically, this is a person who does not consume **caffeine** in any form - coffee, tea, carbonated beverages, etc.

Comment: @Catija I do not drink coffee because I literally hate it and find it disgusting. I am not a Mormon - in fact, coffee is liberally served at meetings of my faith and I'm sure that some people think me weird for not partaking. Oh well.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Mormons are famously supposed to abstain from drinking caffeinated beverages. No strict Mormon church would serve coffee or tea.

Comment: @Catija I know. I said I was not a Mormon. Many non-LDS churches love to serve coffee and tea to congregants.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't see what that has to do with my comment. The reason I said Mormons is **because** they don't drink coffee or tea... other religions have no bearing here. I didn't make a blanket statement that no churches drink coffee or tea. I'm asking the OP to explain their question, not asking people why they dislike these beverages.

Comment: My question is flat simple, I just wanted to know if there actually is a term as such, with no relation whatsoever to religion or any reason for that Matter,  because reasons can be anything, and they differ with each individual, some may just don't like the smell of tea(like my friend which is why I am asking this question in the first place because it got me curious) while others may have other reasons

Comment: @Robert It is perhaps the case that  Catija was being sarcastic when she said 'Mormons'.

Comment: @Alan I don't think she was being sarcastic, may be she was just trying to point out a term for one specific reason not to consume caffeine and Robert was trying to make the point that my question is not just related to one specific practice as he said he doesn't drink coffee not because he is a mormon but finds it disgusting

Comment: I was being sarcastic... You don't become a Mormon just because you don't want to drink caffeine. The reason for my first post was really to figure out why... Regardless, you should add the info from your comments to the questions as further explanation.

Comment: Really the number of people in the world, Mormons included (who knew!), who don't drink tea and coffee must run in hundreds of thousands at the most. When  that number reaches a few millions then someone will coin a phrase, expression or word. It's like asking what do you call people who never  eat white bread. Now someone will tell me that such a word exists... I ain't talking about Celiac sufferers. Because you might not like white bread, or feel that white bread is harmful because it is mass-produced etc. See? Get's too complicated.

Comment: @Catija ‘Vegetarian’ doesn’t include any hints about why you don't eat meat; it just means that you don’t. Why should a word for someone who doesn’t drink tea be any different?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think it kinda does, at least to the degree that you chose to do so. You would describe someone who is too poor to decide if he wants to eat meat or not or has no access to meat for some outside reason a vegetarian. You might say that that person lives vegetarian but that is different.

Comment: @Helmar Yes, it does (generally) imply a choice. It doesn’t say anything about _why_ you choose, though. Most people assume that it’s because of religion/creed or for ‘health reasons’ (even though there aren’t really any), but that’s not down to the word—I’m a vegetarian simply because I don’t like the taste and texture of meat, for instance, but that doesn’t mean a different word would be used to describe me than those who do it for religious reasons. Same with tea: whether it’s a religious thing (like Mormons) or just because they don’t like it, they’re ‘teatotallers’ (as Alan suggests).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree, the *why* is only insofar addressed, that it is an *internal why* and not an *external why.*

Comment: Evidently the world is divided into those who do and those who don't drink either. Give me a cuppa any day. It's my Desert Island beverage of choice once my supply of Krug has run dry.

Comment: This is all Alice-in-Wonderland stuff. Nothing wrong with that, mark you. I'm surprised that no one has gone all scatological and mentioned kopi luwak coffee. Now THAT is what I call disgusting.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is no, there is no specific term for people who do not drink tea or coffee. The general term for someone who avoids something is [abstainer.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abstainer)

> **abstainer**, noun.
>
> 1. a person who abstains from something regarded as improper or unhealthy, especially the drinking of alcoholic beverages.
> 2. a person who abstains from anything.
>
> **abstain**, verb (used without object).
>
> 1. to hold oneself back voluntarily, especially from something regarded as improper or unhealthy (usually followed by from)

Comment: Good point. The *reason* that there is no specific term is that abstention from coffee and tea, especially in an organized and dogmatic manner, is not a significant thing outside Mormonism. Vegetarianism is widely practiced in diverse religious and social communities.

Comment: Abstain wouldn't really work because of the implication of holding back.  It doesn't cover those of us who don't drink tea (or whatever) simply because we don't like the taste.

Comment: @jamesqf there is no word that really works but abstain is as close as it gets. OP asked for a word similar to vegetarian. Vegetarian doesn't differentiate between people who abstain from meat because they don't like the taste and people who abstain for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There is a word you *can use*, but it is not an established word:

**teatotaller**

This is based on the same-sounding word

[teetotaller](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/teetotaller)

which is someone who abstains from alcohol (link to Oxford dictionary online).

Comment: Tea and coffee are not alcoholic drinks. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alcoholic+drink

Comment: @JOSH Nobody said they were.

Comment: So what has teetotaller got to do with the question about tea and coffee?

Comment: @JOSH The answerer is suggesting _teatotaller_. However, the acceptability of this is dubious.

Comment: Surely a word must be established to merit the name?

Comment: Yeesh, it's like people have never heard of a pun...

Comment: @JOSH Did you not notice that the suggested word is spelt _TEA-totaller_ (as opposed to _teetotaller_). It’s a very clever pun, even if the resulting word is not established and would likely be read as a simple typo, or (as with you, it seems) the difference between the two unnoticed entirely.

Comment: I must have missed this hilarious pun.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by some users, there is no established word or term for someone who doesn't drink tea or coffee.

People who avoid consuming carbohydrates are called "[carb-shunner](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22carb-shunner%22&start=10)" and you can consider using a *tea-shunner* and *coffee-shunner*.

The word [*shunner*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/shunner) means

> someone who avoids or keeps away from someone or something.

Or *[non-drinker of coffee](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22non-drinker%20of%20coffee%22&rct=j) (tea)* could be used.

[Yourdictionary.com]

Comment: It'll be teaphobe next. ELU is about established usage, not DIY suggestions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Pls feel free to downvote my answer or close-vote the question. Carb-shunner is somewhat established usage.

Comment: @Rathony - 16 results on Google for "carb-shunner" does not in my opinion constitute "somewhat established usage". Non-drinker of coffee (tea) could be used but the same could be said of any liquid. OP asked for a specific term for people who do not drink tea or coffee. There is no such term.

Comment: @FrankH. Valid point. I included the non-drinker version after the first comment was posted. There is no word or phrase that means "someone who doesn't drink coffee or tea".

Comment: @FrankH. But you need to note that the word *carb-shunner* is broadly used among athletes and bodybuilders who don't consume carbohydrates to maintain or reduce their weight and increase their muscle mass or size. I know it's not a popular term.